# How can I stop position modifier from changing size of View after modification in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am importing my **View/Content** to a **CustomView** for some modification and working on, if I use position modifier on my input **View/Content** and before importing, after importing that **View/Content**, it will takes the screen Size for itself, regardless if the original Size was too large or too small, in other words position modifier, returns kind of all screen in any case. so that make problem and issue for me, because I need to read the true and real size of imported **View/Content**, how can I read the true and real size of my imported **View/Content** in my CustomView? with that in mind that I need to use position on my **View/Content** before getting imported. and it is **not** so cool or convenient to import the Size with the View together. thanks

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView {
            
            //            Rectangle()
            //                .fill(Color.blue)
            //                .frame(width: 200, height: 1000, alignment: .center)
            //                //.position(x: 200, y: 100)      //   <<: this part make our View lose its original size!

            
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
                //.position(x: 200, y: 100)      //   <<: this part make our View lose its original size!
 
        }
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) { self.content = content }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return content()
            .background( GeometryReader { geometry in Color.clear.onAppear() { print(geometry.size) } } )
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `offset()` instead of `position()` because it does not change the original dimensions of **CustomView** though it changes location of **Text("Hello, world!")**.

---

```
 Text("Hello, world!")
    .padding()
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .offset(x: 0, y: -350)
```

---

This article explains the difference of them in depth.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/absolute-positioning-for-swiftui-views